# Even with /Zf, not all names are in MAP file

Tags: windows, assembly, linker, masm

I'm building a project for Wintel-32 with Visual Studio's MASM (it's called `ML`). I request map file generation in linker options. I'm specifying the /Zf option for the assembler (make all symbols global). Yet not all functions appear in the generated map file. Looks like only ones that are imported by other modules appear.

EDIT: there's a bunch of functions that are used only statically (i. e. within the same source file). They are not eliminated from the executable and they shouldn't be. But they don't appear in the MAP file. I want them there.

Those names can be seen if I call `dumpbin /symbols` on the object file (but only with the /Zf). Yet linker strips it from the final executable's map for some reason. The linker options /MAP and /MAPINFO:EXPORTS are there. What am I missing?

EDIT: and /OPT:NOREF too.

Comment: Looks pretty standard behavior. The linker will strip off unused symbols/sections of code. Since this can be done ONLY after the complete call-graph is known, it is done when the final executable is generated. The intermediate object files contain all the symbols/sections.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the following options are enabled in your project.
- [**COMDAT generation** i.e. Function-Level Linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa71f43%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) during compilation.
- [**/OPT=NOREF** linker optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) during linking.

Both the above options tell the compiler/linker to discard unused functions.

For example, update the command invoking the MASM linker **`ML`**, with the **`/OPT`** linker option as follows to retain even unused functions in the final executable:

`ML [you-options] <your-file-name>`**`/link /OPT:REF`**

Comment: It's not that functions themselves are unused and discarded; they are used, but only within their own source file. It's that they're not listed in the MAP file. /OPT:NOREF doesn't help, anyway.

Comment: If you intend to list **ALL** private and public symbols in your exe (wasteful, but required for debugging), then you might want to add **`/Z7`** or **`/Zi`** to the compile flags for MASM.

Comment: /Z7 is not a valid option in my version of MASM. /Zi helped in the sense that debugging became easier, but it didn't help the issue at hand.

Comment: `LINK : warning LNK4224: /MAPINFO:LINES is no longer supported;  ignored`

Comment: Ok, skip that then. Finally add **`/DEBUG /DEBUGTYPE:CV /PDB:NONE`** to your compile flags. AFAIK, this should result in the most "verbose" MAP file possible.